# Does increasing the size of Video element use more bandwidth?

Tags: html, html5-video

I am using Video element to show video streaming.

I have some specific size for video element :

```
<video id="video" autoplay width="262px" height="196px" src=""></video>
```

I want to increase the size of video element but i am not sure whether it will use more bandwidth or not .

So does it use more bandwidth or same bandwidth with low video quality ?

Comment: I believe it wont, Because you're still transferring the same bytes/bits from video source (same file size), while a website like YouTube changes the video source when you change video quality and you can see that for yourself if you have IDM extension

Comment: I also believe same, but i just want to confirm this...
Bandwidth should increased when i will increase resolution of video, not size of video element.

Comment: How much Bandwidth **a video source use Does not depend on its element size on HTML page but on file size**

Comment: hmmm.... right @AdamZapp. But in above comment you said that if i will change the video quality of youtube video then it will change video src . Right ? But it doesn't. Same video src for different video qualities.

Comment: No, YouTube has different sources for each quality of the video! If you were right when I download a video from YouTube I will have to download the highest video quality every time!?

Comment: How can we check youtube video source. I just right clicked on video and copy the URL. It was same for all quality videos.

Answer (score 1):

usually **no**, unless increasing video element will change/effect video source. If source stays same, same bandwidth is used. To test it on your project, you can **use debug tools** (network section) in chrome/firefox.

There was youtube example. Youtube checks video quality that depends on video size, unless is manually set. And then some video part is downloaded. If video quality is small, that part can be 88 KB, if high - 912 KB. (these are numbers from 1 video with 2 different qualities.)